# Revenue Function - Silly Definition

Tags: calculus, education

I'm teaching the section 4.7 on optimization in Stewart Calculus. It has a subsection on "Applications to Business and Economics." There the author defines the price function $p(x)$ to be the price charged if $x$ items have sold, and the revenue function $R(x)$ by the formula $R(x)=xp(x)$.

This seems like an absurd definition to me. For if the demand drops very sharply, say $p(x)=e^{-x}$, then for large $x$, $R(x)$ is approximately 0. In this case the names would suggest the company made nothing, even though they sold many items.

Do people actually use this definition? It seems to me the correct definition would be $R(x)=\int_{0}^{x}p(s)ds$. However, checking the first few results on Google, I only found the given definition. Is my thinking way off-base here?

Answer (score 1):

This is an economics question rather than mathematics.

There is a principle of ["the law of one price"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_one_price) which says that in efficient markets each item sells for the same price as other identical items.

When this applies, the revenue is clearly the number of items sold multiplied by the price per unit.

In your example, it makes no sense for a seller to offer more items for sale than there is demand and then to reduce the price so that all the items are sold.  With a price of $p(x)=e^{-x}$, the revenue $R(x)=xp(x)$ is maximised when $x=1$ and the seller has no incentive to offer more than this for sale: the optimal amount may be less if the seller also has costs.

Comment: Can you explain the assertion "it makes no sense for..." If you don't want the item yourself, you don't expect demand to increase, and it costs nothing to produce (say you have inherited a stockpile of this item), then surely you would want to sell off each copy of the item, no matter if it's sale price per unit is \$100 or \$1. I don't really get why you want to stop selling at any point, if there are no other assumptions on the system.

Comment: If you plan to charge your second customer half the price you charge the fisrt customer, and the third customer half what you charge your second customer, in order to get rid of your stock, and I know this, then I will avoid being your first customer. But if you say that you will destroy the second and third items, then I might be prepared to pay your initial price.

Comment: I take your point to some extent, but (1) there are real world situations which work similarly and people do buy at the higher price (e.g. after so many copies of video game X are sold, it becomes a "Greatest Hit" and its price tag is slashed in half, but people still pay full price to have the game on release). I think even more pertinently, (2) the DEFINITION of revenue should actually compute revenue, independent of whether the company and/or customers are making optimal decisions, and this definition does not do that.